# creating a login form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am trying to develop a system that allows users to create, modify, and add categories for their personal Collections. Users can view the list of Personal Collecions, however to add or modify the items to their Personal Collections a account has to created and the user must login.

It was decided to follow the source code for the login part from the files here at https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-250/revised/blog-after/app from RailsCasts.

Everything else works except the login and registration form.

When trying to load the page I receive the following message:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#create

undefined method `password_digest=' for #<User:0x007fd8540db770>
Rails.root: /Users/laurens14/collections

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `new'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"rqrGlYSK5eSl9+P3WHkSgazwi2zyQyJUiB/G9G6UOU4=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"laurens14@icloud.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
```

This is the source code for the Controllers that is used.

users_controllers:

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
        else
        render "new"
    end
end
end
```

Sessions_controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in!"
        else
        flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
        render "new"
    end
    end

def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
end
  end
```

application_controller:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery

private

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user

def authorize
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not authorized" if current_user.nil?
end
end
```

Collections_controller

```
   class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
   # GET /collections
   # GET /collections.json
   def index
   @collections = Collection.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @collections }
   end
  end

   def list
   end

    # GET /collections/1
   # GET /collections/1.json
  def show
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @collection }
   end
end

  # GET /collections/new
  # GET /collections/new.json
  def new
   @collection = Collection.new

    respond_to do |format|
     format.html # new.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @collection }
    end
    end

    # GET /collections/1/edit
   def edit
   @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
   end

def search
    @collections = Collection.find(:all, :conditions => ["title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:key]}%"])
end


   # POST /collections
   # POST /collections.json
  def create
@collection = Collection.new(params[:collection])

  respond_to do |format|
     if @collection.save
      format.html { redirect_to @collection, notice: 'Collection was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @collection, status: :created, location: @collection }
     else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @collection.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
  end

 # PUT /collections/1
# PUT /collections/1.json
def update
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
   if @collection.update_attributes(params[:collection])
    format.html { redirect_to @collection, notice: 'Collection was successfully updated.'    }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @collection.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
   end

  # DELETE /collections/1
 # DELETE /collections/1.json
 def destroy
   @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
   @collection.destroy

     respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to collections_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
    end
   end
 end
```

Source code for the models:

```
user.rb

      class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_secure_password

        attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

        validates_uniqueness_of :email
       end


collection.rb

        class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
       attr_accessible :date, :description, :instructions, :title, :category_id
       belongs_to :category
     end


catergory.rb

          class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
          attr_accessible :name
          has_many :Collection
      end
```

This is the code that's in the Rake route folder:

```
Collections::Application.routes.draw do
get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

resources :users
resources :sessions

#resources :collections

resources :collections do
    post 'search', :on => :collection
    get 'list', :on => :collection


end
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: can u post the o/p of rake routes... i think /signup should work..try removing the underscore...

Comment: Thanks, I removed the underscore and received a different error message when refreshing the page (see post above). What does o/p mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your migration for the User model. Does it have a column for `password_digest` ? (Column type should be `string`)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I forgot to add password_digest.

Answer (score 0):

add the following lines within the def block for new and then see if it works:

respond_to do |format|

```
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried that and still receive the same error message. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I have added all the controllers.

Comment: can u post your user model code? and also check whether in your Gemfile bycrypt is uncommented

Comment: Sure, added the models source code. I went to terminal on the Mac and typed bundle install. Now getting a different error message (see above).Are login scripts generally quite difficult to create in Ruby on Ralls?

Comment: Most probably this is a case of failed migration..try to fix your test database structure(especially for password_digest column) and also 1thing..after bundle install restart your server once again..